# Powershell cmd to get the contains that is not matching with particular characters

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the all the result that is not contain "Connected" string.
When i am using the cmd `$Logs | Select-string -notmatch "Connected"`

It is filtering disconnected also.

Logs has following string
Connected
Disconnected
Hangup
calling

I want all the lines that not contain Connected.
When I use `$logs | where-object {$_ -notcontains 'Connected'}`

Its having Connected logs also.

Please suggest how can I get the desire output.

Comment: Add a space before and after: " Connected "

Comment: You can use "`^connnected$`"

Comment: You could try using the case sensitive version of ```-notmatch``` - i.e. ```-cnotmatch```. So ```$Logs | Select-string -cnotmatch "Connected"``` - this will then include ```disconnected``` because the ```C``` is a different case, but note that it will also include ```connected``` for the same reason.

Comment: the `Select-String` cmdlet uses _regex pattern matching_ by default. your pattern tells the cmdlet to match ANY instance of the pattern, not the _exact_ pattern. try using the regex word boundary tokens [`\b`] OR simply do as RetiredGeek mentioned &  make the pattern include spaces on each side of the target. ///// this >>> `'connected', 'disconnected' | Select-String -Pattern '\bconnected\b'` <<< will  give only `connected` from the two strings. [*grin*]

Comment: 3: ACCFUL11       @@ACCFULR3     Calling    LOCAL   Tracing  AUTH                            ACCPAS                    
  4: ACCFUL12       @@ACCFULR3     CONNECTED  LOCAL   Tracing  AUTH                            ACCPAS                    
  5: ACCFUL13       @@ACCFULD1     Hagup      LOCAL   Tracing  AUTH                            ACCPAS                    
  6: ACCFUL14       @@ACCFULD2     CONNECTED  LOCAL   Tracing  AUTH                            ACCPAS                    
  7: ACCFUL2        @@ACCFULP2     DISCONNECTED  LOCAL   Tracing  AUTH                            ACCPAS

Comment: The logs i have is like above and i want to get the lines that does not contain CONNECTED string. I tried the above suggestion but unfortunately did not work.

Comment: if i am using select -string i am not able to get the all the other two lines for Hangup and Calling. and for where-object the desire output is not coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably reading `$Logs` from a file with `$Logs = Get-Content -Path 'TheLogFile.log'`.

Below uses a dummy Here-String to mimic that.

To get the lines that do NOT contain `CONNECTED`, best surround it with word boundaries (`\b`) to have Select-Object look for a 'whole word' and add the `-NotMatch` switch:

```
$Logs = @"
3: ACCFUL11 @@ACCFULR3 Calling LOCAL Tracing AUTH ACCPAS
4: ACCFUL12 @@ACCFULR3 CONNECTED LOCAL Tracing AUTH ACCPAS
5: ACCFUL13 @@ACCFULD1 Hangup LOCAL Tracing AUTH ACCPAS
6: ACCFUL14 @@ACCFULD2 CONNECTED LOCAL Tracing AUTH ACCPAS
7: ACCFUL2 @@ACCFULP2 DISCONNECTED LOCAL Tracing AUTH ACCPAS 
"@ -split '\r?\n'

# Select-String returns `MatchInfo` objects. We're only interested in the 'Line' property
($Logs | Select-String '\bCONNECTED\b' -NotMatch).Line
```

Output:

```
3: ACCFUL11 @@ACCFULR3 Calling LOCAL Tracing AUTH ACCPAS
5: ACCFUL13 @@ACCFULD1 Hangup LOCAL Tracing AUTH ACCPAS
7: ACCFUL2 @@ACCFULP2 DISCONNECTED LOCAL Tracing AUTH ACCPAS
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am getting the desire output now.